# C++ accessing map element via pointer object key giving illegal operation error

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

Ok here is the code snippet that I am having the problem with (class name has been changed due to work reason)

```
const std::map<A*, std::pair<int, B*> > &aMap = ot->getAMap();
A *a = getAFromSomewhere();
B* b = aMap[a].second; //The line that the compilation error points to.
```

> Error: The operation "`const std::map<A*, std::pair<int, B*>, std::less<A*>, std::allocator<std::pair<A*const, std::pair<int, B*>>>>[A*]`" is illegal.

anyone has any idea why this is so?

Comment: It is so because it is not valid C++. `B*` is not valid C++.

Comment: Sorry I do not get it why do you say it is not valid.

Comment: aMap[a] should return the pair, and .second should access the B*

Comment: Because it is not. It is not valid according to the specification for the C++ language.

Comment: B here is any user defined class. so I do not see any issue with B* in pair.

Comment: @Mox the issue is in this line: `B* = aMap[a].second;`

Comment: Right. And that's not valid C++. If it were, you would not get the compilation error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, that is not the line that is causing the issue. the issue is the access.

Comment: Your question itself states it's the line with the issue.

Comment: `map` keyed on a pointer is a bit dodgy, anyway. It's really easy to make two `A`s that are identical but at different addresses.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I think you are not understanding the question here. the duplication that is being mark is a totally different error from mine. jesus

Comment: @Mox: you have 2 major problems in one line of code. Ignoring one will not make it disappear.

Comment: @krzaq, could you elaborate further on the other problem?

Comment: @Mox it's what Sam has been talking about. You're lacking variable name. `B* = blah;` is not correct. `B* name = blah;` is.

Comment: @krzaq, this is a simiplified code with unnecessary details removed. i apologize if it is causing confusing. anyway that is not the issue here. ><

Comment: @krzaq, oops, thanks for pointing it out. so sry for the mistake.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, my apology for misunderstanding your statement there.

Comment: No problem, but it shows why it's always useful to provide a full reproducible testcase :)

Comment: @Mox *"the duplication that is being mark is a totally different error from mine. jesus"* If you feel like I made a mistake here, you can edit your question to explain why and the community will review my decision. Although tbh  I'm pretty confident I made the right call in this case.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, while the solution and explanation might be similar, but the scenario is different. When a user encounters a problem, he/she will immediately look for a similar scenario, not a similar solution. If a solution is known, then the user won't even have the problem from the start. So marking a different scenario and similar solution as duplication is doing the users a disfavour. The next user with a scenario similar to mine, will still not be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscript operator for the class `std::map` is declared like

```
T& operator[](const key_type& x);
T& operator[](key_type&& x);
```

As you can see it is declared for non-constant objects of the class because if there is no object in the map with the given key then it is created by the operator.

And your object is constant due to the constant reference

```
const std::map<A*, std::pair<int, B*> > &aMap = ot->getAMap();
^^^^^
```

You should use member function `at` that is declared for constant objects.

```
const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
                               ^^^^^
```

If you have an old compiler that does not support C++ 2011 then you can use member function `find`.

Comment: unfortunately, I cant use at() because the compiler I have here is older than that. so only C++98 is available for me

Comment: @Mox See my updated post.

Comment: thanks for the update, that also answered my question on why my colleague used find in the code. =)

Comment: @Mox Maybe he already asked a similar question at SO, did not he?:)

Answer (score 1):

`aMap` is const, but `std::map::operator[]` is non-const member function (overloads), which can't be called on const object.

Use it with a non-const object will work, e.g.

```
std::map<A*, std::pair<int, B*> > aMap = ot->getAMap(); // aMap is non-const, copied from the returned map
A *a = getAFromSomewhere();
B *b = aMap[a].second;
```

Comment: but the get getAMap() return a const std::map<A*, std::pair<int, B*> > & type. so shouldnt my aMap be const too?

Comment: @Mox Then you can't call `operator[]` on the returned map directly. You can make a copy then call `operator[]` on it like my sample showed, or use `at()` as @ladfromMoscow answered; but note its behavior is not same as `operator[]`. It depends on your needs, if you don't want to insert value if key doesn't exist, then you should use `at()` instead of `operator[]`.

Comment: I will give your solution a shot =)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, just a quick question related to your solution and vlad's. while urs creates a new copy (I assume) but with a O( log N) complexity to find the object, and Vlad's has an O(N) run time for find, which is more recommended ?

Comment: @Mox If you just want to get the element from map, you should use `std::map::find()`, it's O(log N) too.